# Getting Unknown Command error on IF-THEN-ELSE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query that I am using in Oracle 11g

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_MASTER WHERE EMPID='ABCD32643') 
THEN 
update EMPLOYEE_MASTER set EMPID='A62352',EMPNAME='JOHN DOE',EMPTYPE='1' where EMPID='ABCD32643' ;
ELSE 
insert into EMPLOYEE_MASTER(EMPID,EMPNAME,EMPTYPE) values('A62352','JOHN DOE','1') ;
END IF;
```

On running the statement I get the following output:

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
ELSE 
Error report -
Unknown Command


1 row inserted.

Error starting at line : 6 in command -
END IF
Error report -
Unknown Command
```

The values get inserted with error when I run it directly. But when I try to execute this query through my application I get an oracle exception because of the error generated :

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

And hence the values are not inserted.

I am relatively new to Oracle. Please advise on what's wrong with the above query so that I could run this query error free.

Comment: Do you *really* want to change the `EMPID`? Is `EMPID` the primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MERGE` doesn't work for you, try the following:

```
begin
  update EMPLOYEE_MASTER set EMPID='A62352',EMPNAME='JOHN DOE',EMPTYPE='1' 
    where EMPID='ABCD32643' ;
  if SQL%ROWCOUNT=0 then
    insert into EMPLOYEE_MASTER(EMPID,EMPNAME,EMPTYPE)
      values('A62352','JOHN DOE','1') ;
  end if;
end;
```

Here you you the `update` on spec, then check whether or not you found a matching row, and `insert` in case you didn't.

Comment: Worked just perfect!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "what's wrong with the above query "

What's wrong with the query is that it is not a query (SQL). It should be a program snippet (PL/SQL) but it isn't written as PL/SQL block, framed by `BEGIN` and `END;` keywords.

But turning it into an anonymous PL/SQL block won't help. Oracle PL/SQL does not support `IF EXISTS (select ...` syntax.

Fortunately Oracle SQL does support MERGE statement which does the same thing as your code, with less typing.

```
merge into EMPLOYEE_MASTER em
using ( select 'A62352' as empid,
               'JOHN DOE' as empname,
               '1' as emptype
         from dual ) q
on (q.empid = em.empid)
when not matched then
    insert (EMPID,EMPNAME,EMPTYPE) 
           values (q.empid, q.empname, q.emptype)
when matched then
    update 
    set em.empname = q.empname, em.emptype = q.emptype
/
```

Except that you're trying to update `empid` as well. That's not supported in `MERGE`. Why would you want to change the primary key?

> "Does this query need me to add values to all columns in the table?  "

The `INSERT` can have all the columns in the table. The `UPDATE` cannot change the columns used in the `ON` clause (usually the primary key) because that's a limitation of the way MERGE works. I think it's the same  key preservation mechanism we see when updating views. [Find out more](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:548422757486).

Comment: Does this query need me to add values to all columns in the table?

Comment: I have a few more columns in the table but those are nullable. And I tried running the query you put up and I am getting this error: Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 12
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values

Comment: Then you need to change the INSERT statement to specify the columns in play. I have corrected my code to fit the columns you have in your post

Comment: I used all columns in my insert statement but still continue to get the same error and If you noticed the error points to the first line of the query which means the merge probably needs to have all columns listed as well (Totally making a wild guess)

Comment: My solution applies the columns you used in your question. If you want to use more columns you need to amend that solution, by adding columns to the sub-query in the USING clause. This is not the only way of passing parameters to the query, it's just a standalone example.